# Sqlalchemy, python, easiest way to populate database with data

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I tend to start projects that are far beyond what I am capable of doing, bad habit or a good way to force myself to learn, I don't know. Anyway, this project uses a postgresql database, python and sqlalchemy. I am slowly learning everything from sql to sqlalchemy and python. I have started to figure out models and the declarative approach, but I am wondering: what is the easiest way to populate the database with data that needs to be there from the beginning, such as an admin user for my project? How is this usually done?

Edit:

Perhaps this question was worder in a bad way. What I wanted to know was the possible ways to insert initial data in my database, I tried using sqlalchemy and checking if every item existed or not, if not, insert it. This seemed tedious and can't be the way to go if there is a lot of initial data. I am a beginner at this and what better way to learn is there than to ask the people who do this regularly how they do it? Perhaps not a good fit for a question on stackoverflow, sorry.

Comment: There's the "easiest" way, then there is the "usually done" way. They are not necessarily the same. The easiest, AFAIC, is to put all of the SQL into one SQL script and run it. However, what happens when you change your projects schema over the life of the project? In that case, there are tools like Alembic which would say to create migrations. This is a bit more difficult initially, but might make it easier to evolve your "initial" data over time (so you don't have to rewrite that one script every time you make changes). As you can see, there is no "easiest" way, since it really depends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a schema change management tool like liquibase. Normally this is used to keep your database schema in source control, and apply patches to update your schema.

You can also use liquibase to load data from CSV files. So you could add a startup.csv file in liquibase that would be run the first time you run liquibase against your database. You can also have it run any time, and will merge data in the CSV with the database.